# Sikulix and Selenium integration in Pycharm project

Tags: selenium, pycharm, sikuli

Looking for step-by-step  instructions how to integrate Sikulix  with Selenium in Pycharm IDE. Would like to combine Sikuli and selenium webdriver for unittesting.
I have already downloaded SikuliX as standalone IDE for Jython2.7. In my Pycharm IDE I have some sikuli packages available. See attached. I do not know which ones to download. Also, still confused if I need to dowload Jython or not.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Download selenium python bindings from https://pypi.python.org/simple/selenium/

2) Extract that to a folder and run python setup.py install from there.

3) Now, copy the generated "selenium" folder to your \python\Lib and \jython\Lib root directories

4) Test your code by typing "from selenium import webdriver" in your file.

5) For sikuli, just edit your pycharm run configuration and include this in your environment variables "CLASSPATH=C:\Sikuli\sikulixapi.jar;PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"

6) Use jython as your project interpreter